# force allocate char[] (string) in the stack instead of global

Tags: c++, string, gcc, stack

Im trying to force the compiler to allocate inline strings in the stack:
This code allocate the the string in .rdata section:

```
foo("test");
```

While this code allocate the string in the stack:

```
char szt1[] = "test1";
foo(szt1);
```

Which is exactly what i want to force.

How is it possible to force the compile to always allocate the array in the stack?
Im using gcc.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you already have the answer? Just use your second snippet...

Comment: Serious question: *why* do you want to do this? I'm genuinely curious why you'd really want this. Perhaps you'll teach me something new if you've got a good reason.

Comment: What happens if you use the '-fwritable-strings' gcc option? I've never used it, just thought it might help. It's supposed to disable string pooling.

Comment: The second code snippet has a char pointer allocated on the stack, pointing to static data "test1". The stack cannot have static assigned to it at compile time. The address of the stack is unknown at compile time.

Comment: -fno-const-strings & -fwritable-strings are not supported on g++ 4.9.2

Comment: Its not convenient to declare the strings everytime as char[] instead of simply passing them directly to the function.

Comment: @user3575889 Why do you have to declare it as `char[]` again? As your example shows, you could simply pass them directly.

Comment: @KeithSmith: That is not true. The second snippet does not point to static data. The array `szt1` is locally mutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no good way to do this, and probably not many good reasons to desire this behavior.

If you don't want the string to exist in a data segment, the closest you can do is allocating an automatic array of `char` and assigning the characters to it, one at a time.

```
char hello[6] = {};
hello[0] = 'h'; hello[1] = 'e'; hello[2] = 'l'; hello[3] = 'l'; hello[4] = 'o';
```

Comment: You don't need the `strcpy()`.  `char hello[] = "hello"` stores the string literal characters in the data segment (same with your example), then at runtime allocates the array on the stack and copies the characters into the array.  Using `strcpy()` would just be an explicit means of doing the same thing that the compiler does implicitly.

Comment: `char hello[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o',0};` is the same thing, but much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The oneliner is `foo(std::string("test").c_str());`

Ok, technically you don't know that the small string optimization will kick in, but OTOH you don't even know whether a conventional stack exists.